# Update record in Acess 2007 and returned rows by means of C#

Tags: c#

```
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cb_employees;
            cb_employees = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da_employees);

            DataRow[] returned_rows_employee;
            returned_rows_employee = ds_employees.Tables["EMPLOYEES"].Select("NIP_EMPLOYEES='" + textNipSearch.Text + "'");

            DataRow row_employees;
            row_employees = returned_rows_employee[0];
            textPesel.Text = row_employees["PESEL_EMPLOYEES"].ToString();
            textName.Text = row_employees["NAME_EMPLOYEES"].ToString();
            textSurname.Text = row_employees["SURNAME_EMPLOYEES"].ToString();
            textPlace.Text = row_employees["PLACE_EMPLOYEES"].ToString();
            textStreet.Text = row_employees["STREET_EMPLOYEES"].ToString();
            textPostalcode.Text = row_employees["POSTAL_CODE_EMPLOYEES"].ToString();
            textNip.Text = textNipSearch.Text;
            textPhone.Text = row_employees["PHONE_CONTACT_EMPLOYEES"].ToString();'
```

I would like search in DataBase employee about NIP = textNipSearch.Text, OK it work's but I want to know number returned row.... How??

I greet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not missing something here, you already have a collection of DataRow objects, so a simple

```
returned_rows_employee.Length
```

would return the number of items in that collection.

Comment: Franz, `returned_rows_employee.Lenght` returned length array in result. I want to know number of the detect row, example:

NIP 11-22

My array in database, name: EMPLOYEE:

    Row 1  - John Kowalksy 11-00
    Row 2  - Pablo Numeric 11-22

and query returned to `returned_rows_employee` row 2, and I want know numeric this row :)

Comment: Ah, so you want to get the index of the selected row in your array?
But why would you want that? Why is the row number so important? It can change if you use sort by option... Can't you edit your SQL statement to get that one single row you're looking for? Or am I missing something again? :P
Anyway, try iterating through your collection with a foreach loop, and get the index of the current item, if it is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Well if you have a primary or unique key in your data table, then it's pretty straightforward. Update employees set values where primaryKey=somethingUnique :P
cheers